# Native iOS app that contains post like Facebook website / app

Tags: ios, layout, view, uiwebview, native

I know for sure this is a stupid question but I've realized after some months developing an small app that really contains a web view, struggling with some feature as a mixed of web / native views for adding a post or notification banners, slide menus, etc, that I do not know how to migrate web areas to a native view.
I was thinking the natural way to do it were adding a table view and data to table cells but right now I'm not pretty sure about that. I'm adding an screenshot about how newsfeed page should look like.
As you can see it can contain an image (or not), some text and some areas to add a comment (hidden while no clicked over "Comment" button), likes and so on.

My main concern is about to move that layout to a native view and a control that iterates n-times populating it with data from DB (JSON calls are already made in web application making it easier).

Thanks a lot

[image]

Comment: Consider getting rid of comment button and just give them a place to comment with a button to submit.

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is here.

Comment: Well, first thing is I cannot change the look of it. It has to have same layout as web app (all elements).On the other hand the thing is about app design (layouts). Coming from MVC.NET I'm still looking for a view or partial view instead making views with code all the time. It seems that iOS doesn't allow to make "visual or physical" partial views and blocks and you have to code them all the time. Is it that way?. Because I'm not sure how to make this kind of views with blocks that are populated n-time.Must I code the partial view or could I use some UI element to build it?.Thanks